# Pivoting tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table like this:

```
serialnumber   partnb  id  actual      nominal
1               1       AGR 15,2176803  15,2
1               1       APR 5,8060656   5,8
1               1       DCI 61,9512259  62
1               43      AGR 15,4178727  15,4
1               43      APR 7,235779    7,2
1               43      DCI 52,0080535  52
2               2       AGR 15,2097009  15,2
2               2       APR 5,8009968   5,8
2               2       DCI 61,9582795  62
2               44      AGR 15,4191387  15,4
2               44      APR 7,2370065   7,2
2               44      DCI 52,010244   52
```

And I want this:

```
serialnumber   partnb  AGR AGR_nominal APR APR_nominal     DCI DCI_nominal
1               1   15,217  15,2        5,806   5,8     61,951  62
1               43  15,417  15,2        7,235   7,2     52,008  62
2               2   15,209  15,2        5,800   5,8     61,958  62
2               44  15,419  15,4        7,237   7,2     52,010  52
```

How can I achieve this in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution

```
  SELECT 
    planid,
    serialnumber,
    partnb,
    DFI,
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='DFI') AS nominal_DFI,
    DCI, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='DCI') AS nominal_DCI,
    DPI, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='DPI') AS nominal_DPI,
    AGR, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='AGR') AS nominal_AGR,
    APR, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='APR') AS nominal_APR,
    DGR, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='DGR') AS nominal_DGR,
    DPR, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='DPR') AS nominal_DPR,
    DFE, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='DFE') AS nominal_DFE,
    DKE, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='DKE') AS nominal_DKE,
    MDKE, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='MDKE') AS nominal_MDKE,
    MDKI, 
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='MDKI') AS nominal_MDKI,
    DKI,
    (SELECT nominal FROM vwMeasurement v WHERE p.planid=v.planid 
        AND p.serialnumber=v.serialnumber AND p.partnb=v.partnb 
        AND v.id='DKI') AS nominal_DKI
  FROM(SELECT DISTINCT serialnumber, planid, partnb, id, actual FROM vwMeasurement) driver
  PIVOT (
    SUM(driver.actual) 
    FOR driver.id IN (DFI, DCI, DPI, AGR, APR, DGR, DPR, DFE, DKE, MDKE, MDKI, DKI)
  ) AS p
  ORDER BY planid, serialnumber, partnb
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a PIVOT keyword in Sql Server 2005 you can use. Here is the description http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: I have found the solution with the PIVOT feature. Now I understand the sintaxis and it's cool :)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but you could create separate views for AGR, APR and DCI and join them on id.

Comment: Yes, I could, but the problem is that this result set has been simplified.

I couldn't because there are too joins to do.